# Creating a truth table in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

### e1 - Create a truth-table

Create a module called `e1_truthtable` in a file `e1_truthtable.v` that implements the
following truth-table, where `a` and `b` are inputs, and `x` and `y`
are outputs. All truth-table values are decimal numbers or `X` for
don't care.

| a[0] | a[1] | a[2] | b[3:0] | x | y[2:0] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 0 | X | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 0 | X | 1 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | X |

```
module truth_table(
       input logic[2:0] a,
       input logic[3:0] b,
       output logic x,
       output logic[2:0] y
    );
       assign x = (a[2] & b[2]) || (&a & b[1]);
    
endmodule
```

```
module test_bench();
       logic [2:0] a;
       logic [3:0] b;
       logic x;
       logic [2:0] y;

    initial begin
    a = 'b100;
    b = 'b0100;
    $display("x = 0x%0b", x);
    #1
    a = 'b110;
    b = 'b0100;
    $display("x = 0x%0b", x);

    #1
    a = 'b111;
    b = 'b0010;
    $display("x = 0x%0b", x);

    #1
    a = 'b000;
    b = 'b0011;
    $display("x = 0x%0b", x);

    #1
    a = 'b000;
    b = 'b0100;
    $display("x = 0x%0b", x);

    #1
    a = 'b000;
    b = 'b0101;
    $display("x = 0x%0b", x);

    #1
    a = 'b000;
    b = 'b0110;
    $display("x = 0x%0b", x);

    end

    truth_table tb(
    .a(a),
    .b(b),
    .x(x),
    .y(y)
    );

endmodule
```

Hi guys, I'm new to Verilog and I'm trying to solve the truth table above. However, I'm only doing the part for x first. Currently, I am getting an error saying that reg x cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignments. Moreover, it says output port expression must support continuous assignment and port 3 (x) of truth_table is connected to x. Could anyone give me some pointers on how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: There are no such errors in your code. I cannot reproduce them. Which tool did you use? Note, that this is a system verilog syntax, not the classic verilog. Some tools, however, understand '.v' file extension as a classic verilog file.

Comment: @Serge I use WSL, Ubuntu and iverilog to try and compile it. But, I get various errors.

Comment: iverilog does not fully support system verilog syntax.